# find line with specific string and move this string to the beginning of the line

Tags: regex, notepad++

is there a way to move specific srtring of the line to the beginning of the line with Notepad++?

here's lines:

```
Chevrolet '96 Corvette COUPE [AP] [2] 
Chevrolet '96 Corvette COUPE [AP] [2] [RM]
Chevrolet '96 Corvette GRAND SPORT [AP] [2] 
Chevrolet '96 Corvette GRAND SPORT [AP] [2] [RM]
Chevrolet Camaro Z28 [AP] [2] 
Chevrolet Camaro Z28 [AP] [2] [RM]
Chevrolet Camaro Z28 30th Anniversary [P] 
Chevrolet Camaro Z28 30th Anniversary [P] [RM]
Chevrolet Corvette '67 427COUPE [3] [US/EU] [A] [4]
```

here's what I want them to be:

```
Chevrolet '96 Corvette COUPE [AP] [2] 
[RM] Chevrolet '96 Corvette COUPE [AP] [2]
Chevrolet '96 Corvette GRAND SPORT [AP] [2] 
[RM] Chevrolet '96 Corvette GRAND SPORT [AP] [2]
Chevrolet Camaro Z28 [AP] [2] 
[RM] Chevrolet Camaro Z28 [AP] [2]
Chevrolet Camaro Z28 30th Anniversary [P] 
[RM] Chevrolet Camaro Z28 30th Anniversary [P]
Chevrolet Corvette '67 427COUPE [3] [US/EU] [A] [4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `[RM]` the only substring you want to move to the beginning of the line? In that case do the following:
Open the replace window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> then select "Regular expression" under "Search Mode".

Then search for the following:

```
(.*?)\[RM]
```

And replace it with the following:

```
\[RM] \1
```